# What is this bass belt strap?

Tags: electric-bass-guitar

I have never seen a bass belt strap like this:

[image]
[image]

My guess would be that it is kind of safer than the normal strap, but I'm not sure

Can I use a normal belt? Do I need some kind of special belt?

Comment: Here are some more pics: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kc14u5weip7kv2g/AABmeNDTnD7GLSrN-Yq58Mwua?dl=0)

Comment: A lot of them are designed so an ordinary strap will still fit. Guitar and bass use the same thing. Some tie-clips from the past used the same sort of mechanism.

Comment: In fact, a traditional [I mean really old style] clip-on beer bottle top rubber surround is almost as good. Grolsch used that old-style bottle for quite some time, all my other guitars have the 'rubber ring' strap lock - one free with every beer ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a strap-lock, unfortunately without the corresponding locking part.

[image]

Mine on my old Rikki are Schaller, same as [this](http://www.guitarguitar.co.uk/guitar_care_detail.asp?stock=04091512084428&gclid=CjwKEAiAk8qkBRDOqYediILQ5BMSJAB40A5UrpC6IJVIjTDHTw3IA7BGylgunxQYqoZpo0YmspPm6xoCSi_w_wcB), though no doubt there are other makers.

From comments, a Grolsch beer bottle 'rubber washer' from their old-fashioned bottle tops makes a great free substitute
[image]

[image]

Comment: The images in the question are rather poor, but they don't seem to be the classic Schaller's you've posted. But it's definitely some system like it.

Comment: They do look like a 'copy' yes, without the chamfered edge. Mine are definitely the ones in the picture above. (I've had them 30 years & the strap never came off without me telling it to;) Functionally the same, I'd guess - but unlikely to be interchangeable.

Comment: Can I buy just the top part of a new one? Or a whole new one and just replace the top part?

Comment: Also, I use a normal belt, right?

Comment: You'd have to figure out what make it is - yours doesn't look interchangeable with the Schaller. I haven't looked, but my guess would be they all come as a complete kit. It's only a case of unscrewing one pair of buttons & screwing in the other; even if the threads don't quite match, either re-using the old screws, or a bit of wood filler would sort it. I actually had zero difficulty when I swapped mine, all those years ago.

Comment: Normal strap, yes. The 'lock' part goes through the regular hole at each end & then you just add the metal washer & tighten it down with the nut. In use, the strap just hooks onto the button & clicks in - slightly different move to a regular strap but takes an whole minute to get used to it ;) It will only come off again if you pull the knob that sticks out the top.

Comment: The only downside is that a normal strap can be used on strap-lock buttons, but once you fasten the locks to a strap, you can only use it on a strap-lock guitar